# I think I just coughed a little blood, have been dry coughing for 2-3 days. What should I do?

Tags: blood, cough

This is what my cough looks like, verify blood :( https://ibb.co/gD6Otv

https://ibb.co/hE4nLa

Comment: Visit a doctor.

Comment: As Narusan said, see a doctor. Nobody on the internet can tell you what's wrong and coughing blood is never something to be taken lightly.

Comment: Doesn't look like hemoptysis to me. It is blood streaked, so maybe some URTI like a throat infection. No need to worry, but nonetheless you should be visiting a doctor.

Comment: @Polisetty The fact that only a small amount of blood was visible doesn't speak to the source or clinical significance. I recommend that you wait until you're a licensed physician and have examined the patient before telling them "no need to worry."